# Error when trying to compose a message in a case

Tags: email, case, insufficient-privileges

One of my agents is trying to send an email from the Case Feed, but when he tries to compose the email he gets an Insuficient Privileges error (see image).

[image: Case email error message]

Other agents that have the same Profile do not have this error.
What should I look for?

-- Addendum --
We setup the Salesforce extension in Chrome lately, I am not sure if it is related...  because the agent told me that he once sent an email successfully before that.

Comment: Sorry can you post the English translation of the error message?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It is `You do not have sufficient privileges for this operation. Contact the owner of this record or the system administrator`

Comment: Thanks @PranayJaiswal, and yes the agent is the owner of the record.